# PHP cross session variable

Tags: php, variables, memory, global

in order to prevent server from  accessing intensively my database or filesystem, I need a memory variable, which will be accessible by all scripts regardless of session on my server. I assumed putenv/setenv (or $_ENV) can be used, but it’s not working for on my server when I do putenv in one script and I echo it in another one. Am I doing anything wrong? I found SHMOP functions as well, but they don’t work on Windows – is there anything like this, which works under both Windows and Unix/Linux? Any hint is welcome.

Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to store the information locally in memory on the server, or a distributed cache like Memcache.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

1. Create a RAMDisk
2. write a file into the RAMDisk.

Comment: ...and implement file locking too to avoid race conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Use memcached.

http://memcached.org/

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php